# d3 - nested selections/sub-item update issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm getting used to d3, but seem to be having trouble with more advanced structures.  I'm fairly sure there's some subtlety or concept I am not fully appreciating.  I want to be able to mirror a changing hierarchical data structure with a changing hierarchical element structure.

My data structure is 3 groups, each with 3 items.  Each group and item has a unique key, extracted using a key function in the `data()` call.

I build the structure, and I can remove a top-level item; `.exit().remove()` works just fine on that selection.  BUT, modifying or removing any sub-item is simply not reflected in the generated element structure.

Full (non-)working jsFiddle here!: http://jsfiddle.net/eu95R/2/, and the all-important enticingly beautiful screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your definition of `groups` is using `svg.enter()` and the subselection is made on `groups`. That is, you're not seeing a change because `groups` in this case is empty (no enter selection for the SVGs) and therefore there's no subselection.

To fix, simply do the subselection based on e.g. `svg` (there are a number of ways to fix this -- not saying that this is necessarily the best one). As you are appending the elements to a `g` within the SVG, the selector would be `svg.selectAll("g").selectAll("text.item")...`.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eu95R/4/).

Comment: Thank you, however can you explain - that does not produce a similar hierarchy of elements; the items aren't added to an element for each group, but directly to the 'svg'.  In my real case, the group elements have data relating the group, but also apply a transform which child elements should inherit.  Is there a way to map hierarchical data -> hierarchical elements in that way?

Comment: Ah well spotted! I missed the additional `g` element. All you need is an additional `.selectAll()` here, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: sneaky I know, but you haven't any ideas on my .exit()/.order() transition issue, do you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418934/keeping-element-order-selection-order-with-exit-transitions-in-d3/24423857#24423857