# Keeping element order (selection.order) with exit transitions in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'll cut to the chase with the **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/K6Yrw/ [click the second button to see the effect quickly]

---

I'm using `selection.order` because I need my DOM elements to exist in the same order as the data elements.

I want to add a transition to my `.exit()` selection.  However, when combined with `.order()`,  the process breaks down.  The item being removed is placed at the beginning of the list of DOM elements.

My guess: Perhaps because `order` tries to get the index of the element in the data array - of course it no longer exists, and so gets `-1` as the index, meaning it should be sorted to the beginning of the DOM element list.

If I don't use `order` then the exit transition works just fine: but if I insert something part-way through the data array, of course the new DOM element is just appended to the end.

Any tips or assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. I get the same order with and without `selection.order()`. The DOM elements will be appended in the same order as the data elements by default, you don't need to do anything in addition to get that.

Comment: Lars - they are always appended, never inserted.  Inserting an item at index 3 in the data will result in it being appended at the end of the list of DOM elements.  `order()` works around that, but in the case of an `exit()` selection, it always orders elements relating to removed data to the very start of the DOM list.

Comment: Still don't really understand what you're aiming for here. Perhaps you have a more complex example in mind where this matters?

Comment: The fiddle should show it - a simple list of DOM elements, I want them to retain the ordering that their underlying data has.  I want to animate the removal of an item from that list.  At the same time, an inserted item should appear at the location it was inserted.  If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now -- I was missing the inserting bit. You're basically seeing this because you're using a transition. What you need to do is order *after* the remove transition is complete. This is relatively easy when using the `.each("end", ...)` handler. The snag is that you also need to run this when the exit selection is empty, which requires a separate check. http://jsfiddle.net/K6Yrw/47/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have a solution.  The problem is that d3 ends up sorting more than just the elements in your selection.  The exited elements are no longer part of your selection and d3 inadvertently moves them.  I modified the existing d3 order function so that it takes a key function and skips anything not in the current selection.  This way the exited elements just stay put.  My version needs a key to check if an element is in the current selection.  Not sure if there is a better way to handle that or not.

```js
function strictOrder(fnKey){
    fnKey = fnKey || function(d){return d;};

    return function(){
        for (var j = -1, m = this.length; ++j < m; ) {

            for (var group = this[j], i = group.length - 1, next = group[i], node,seen = new d3.set(); --i >= 0; ) {
                node = group[i];
                if (!node)  continue;

                if (next && next !== node.nextSibling && (!node.nextSibling || seen.has(fnKey(node.nextSibling.__data__)))){
                    next.parentNode.insertBefore(node, next);
                }

                seen.add(fnKey(node.__data__));
                next = node;
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
}
```

see your forked fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/co8nqopy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try just running selection.order only when you are inserting items and not when you are deleting items.

So to correct the fiddle you would add an argument to the method doD3() that holds true/false as to whether or not to run selection.order.  So pass true when you are inserting items in order to preserve order and false when you remove items.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6Yrw/31/

```
var items = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'aardvark'];

function doD3(order) {
    var selection = d3.select('div.c')
        .selectAll('p')
    .data(items, function(d) { return d; });

    selection
        .enter()
        .append('p')
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 1);

    selection
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .remove();

    if(order) {
        // remove this to see alternative behaviour
        selection
            .order();    
    }    
}

doD3(true);

$('#b1').click(function() {
    items.splice(1, 0, ['kiwi']);
    doD3(true);
});

$('#b2').click(function() {
    items.splice(2, 1);
    doD3(false);
});
```

Comment: Interesting, but of course that means I can't update+delete or insert+delete at the same time.  And, I can't delete then insert or update while the delete transition is running.?